# Building Qt Application Release Configuration With Symbols

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm currently using Qt Creator under Windows to build my application and was looking in to building my application in release configuration with debug symbols but found nothing for MSVCC.  I currently have a bug in my application which only occurs under release configuration and not debug, so being able to hit breakpoints under release would be a great help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If switching to CMake is an option (I believe QtCreator supports both CMake and QMake projects), then you can use CMake's "RelWithDebInfo" build type to accomplish what you're looking for.

However, if CMake is not an option, you may be able to adjust your project file to include debug information:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -Zi
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -Zi
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += /DEBUG /OPT:REF
```

Or if you're using GCC / mingw:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -g
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -g
```